# SwingUtilities.invokeLater ... is there an invokeNow?

Tags: java, swing, invokelater

[I had a problem earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206237/java-null-pointer-exception-passing-object) where I was trying to add objects to my canvas but the SwingUtilities.invokeLater hadn't really done its job yet. I really need to be able to add things reliably to this JPanel but I keep running into this same error. Is there a better alternative to the below code?

```
private void startNewGame() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gameFrame = new InvadersGameFrame();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As an aside: I entered that answer before carefully reading the question.  `invokeLater` has always worked reliably for me.  The problem is elsewhere.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: I think that the invocations of `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` are queued. That means that if you call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to add the object to the jpanel before calling it to add `new InvadersGameFrame();` the first invocation should be executed before the second one.

Comment: This smells strongly like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait-java.lang.Runnable-) which:

> Causes `doRun.run()` to be executed **synchronously** on the AWT event dispatching thread. This call blocks until all pending AWT events have been processed and (then) `doRun.run()` returns. This method should be used when an application thread needs to update the GUI.

Comment: Does what I asked perfectly.